# Result of AVCaptureMovieFileOutput is different from what's seen in AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer when zoomed in with stabilization turned on

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm working on an app that records and saves video to the user's camera roll. My setup: I'm using an `AVCaptureSession` with an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` for the preview and `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` for the saved file.

Under most circumstances, what is seen in the preview layer matches up with the saved video asset, but if I turn on stabilization (either `AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.standard` or `AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.cinematic`), and set the zoom factor very high (around 130), then the preview and the output become noticeably offset from each other.

[The output is consistently above and slightly to the right of what's shown in the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JOGx.png). I suspect this happens at smaller zoom factors as well, but the effect is minimal enough to only be noticeable at higher zoom factors.

Part of the reason for turning stabilization on in the first place is to more easily line objects up when zoomed in, so merely limiting zoom or turning off stabilization isn't really an option.

I'm curious to know why the preview and output aren't in sync, but ultimately I'm looking for a possible solution that lets me keep 1. zoom 2. stabilization and 3. an accurate preview.

**UPDATE: Dec. 12**

After messing around with this some more, it seems that sometimes the issue doesn't happen using `cinematic` stabilization, and my new theory is that it might have to do with specific combinations of `AVCaptureDeviceFormat`s and stabilization settings.

Comment: Interesting. And definitely an oddball enough case to be worth [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) or bringing up on [Apple's developer forums](http://devforums.apple.com), even if it turns out to be intended behavior.